# take the value of enum and covert it to String

Tags: java

I should take from a variable enum its value and transform it to string.how can i do?

here it is the type enum:

```
 public enum State{
      b,c,p;

 };
```

now i have to insert into an object String one value.

Comment: enum has methods to do this. You will want to check the API.

Comment: I haven't find it.I found values()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `enum.name` or`enum.toString` to get the name of the enum constant, or `enum.ordinal` to get the ordinal position.

Answer (score 2):

you can use name() or toString(), so :

```
State aState = State.c;
String strState = aState.name();
```

See [here](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) the official java reference for more information...

Answer (score 2):

`State.b.toString()` will return `"b"`. The same goes for the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Usually,

```
State state = ...;
String string = state.toString();
```

should work, but it is not recommended since someone might override `toString` for some other purpose.

Instead the method you are looking for is

```
String string = state.name();
```

As an aside, your enumerated stated should always be all in capitals, and they should have descriptive names.  It's not a language rule, but a convention. For example `enum State { ON, OFF, PAUSED; }`.

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1: Using the built-in [`toString()`](http://java.xiruibin.com/Enum.html#toString%28%29) and [`name()`](http://java.xiruibin.com/Enum.html#name%28%29) methods**

If you want to print a `String` that is the same as the value of the `State`, then you can use the `toString()` method, or the `name()` method.

```
System.out.println(State.b); // Prints "b"
System.out.println(State.c); // Prints "c"
System.out.println(State.p); // Prints "p"
```

**Method #2: Using a constructor to create a custom mapping**

If you want to have a custom `String` associated with each of those states, you can use a constructor to associate a particular value with each `enum` value:

```
public enum State{
    b("State B"), c("State C"), p("State P");

    private String longName;
    private State(String longName) {
        this.longName = longName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.longName;
    }
};
```

Of course, if you don't want to break the default `toString()` usage, you can create a different method called `getFullName()`, for example, to return the custom value.

Comment: It would be shorter to just have only one `@Override public String toString { return "State " + name().toUpperCase(); }`, which you can put after the the declaration `a ,c, p;`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I was using `State B`, etc. as sample Strings.  Someone might want to map `b` to `"Banana"` and `c` to `"Coconut"`, for example, in which case there is no hard and fast way to implement the `toString()` logic.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do something more complicated, but I find that it's more flexible:

```
public enum MyEnumeration {
    SOME_NAME("Some Name"),
    OTHER_THING("Other Thing"),
    ...
    MORE_VALUES("More Values"),

    private final String displayName;

    private MyEnumeration(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

This way, I use standard capitalization for my enums in code, but can have a more presentable name for them. 
This trick can also be used to replace ordinal, by initializing a number, and then you don't need to worry about rearranging your enums.